# ¿Cómo puedo hacer para que en una columna de DataTables Primefaces, en una celda aparezca un boton y otra un texto?

Tags: java, jsf, java-ee, primefaces

Es decir que, dependiendo del valor que haya en la base de datos, sea que aparezca la celda.

La idea es:
Si hay una cantidad de articulo, aparezca un botón en la columna. Si no hay artículos, que el valor sea cero, aparezca un texto, por ejemplo, "Sin articulo".
El código siguiente solo me muestra el botón.

```
<p:column headerText="Seleccion">  
  <p:commandButton update=":idFormLibros" oncomplete="PF('libroDialog').show()" value="Seleccionar" styleClass="ui-button-raised ui-button-success ui-button-flat">                               
  </p:commandButton>
</p:column>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Como no veo todo el código no puedo ver tus variables, pero suponiendo que tienes el valor de la cantidad de artículos como una columna podrías hacer algo así:

```
<p:column headerText="Seleccion">  
  <p:commandButton update=":idFormLibros" oncomplete="PF('libroDialog').show()" value="Seleccionar" styleClass="ui-button-raised ui-button-success ui-button-flat"
    rendered="#{fila.columna > 0}">         
  </p:commandButton>
  
  <h:outputText value="Sin articulo" rendered="#{fila.columna == 0}" />
</p:column>
```

Comment: Saludos. Muchas gracias. 
Sí, funciona. Solo tuve que cambiar algunas variables y código desde la clase java.